# Automate Approval Step to be approved, not skipped

Tags: case, automation, approval-process

We're currently tracking internal requests in Salesforce via Cases. For a certain kind of request, we want to run it by the managers of 3 teams to see if what's being requested would be applicable to their team. Depending on the "yea" or "nays", we would then know to either implement the request for all, some, or none of the teams.

I'm trying to get this set up through Approval Processes, but the issue here is that a "Reject" vote shouldn't reject the request entirely, it should just mark the request as undesired by that particular team, and pass the request along to the next manager.

I thought I came up with a genius workaround by inserting Approval Steps for myself in between each Approval Step for the managers. My Steps would be skipped unless the "X Team Reviewed" checkbox was checked, and those checkboxes would be checked as "Rejection Actions" for the next Approval Step, which would "Go Back 1 Step" when rejected.

So example: Case enters Approval Process. Step 1 skips automatically because "X Team Reviewed" checkbox is unchecked. Step 2 goes to X Team - if they then choose "Reject", box is checked and it goes back to Step 1 (me). I then Approve, and Step 2 is set to skip if "X Team Reviewed" is CHECKED, so they aren't asked again and it goes to the next manager. Before each manager's approval step, there's a similar step for myself that should be skipped the first time but is reverted to if the manager rejects.

The problem is, as I learned, that "Go Back 1 Step" logic for rejections is actually "Go Back to Last Approver", and technically a skipped approval step is not an approval. So if Step 1 is skipped and Step 2 is rejected, it doesn't revert to Step 1 - it searches for a previous approver, finds none, and goes to final rejection.

In other words, my plan here only works if the "me" Steps are never skipped and I have to manually approve every time. Before resigning myself to this fate or other workarounds, I wanted to ask the community:

1) is there any way I can automate approvals for all my steps, without skipping the steps?

2) Am I missing a much smarter way to be doing this?

Thanks!

[image: my original process]